# PHP Filter drop down data according to drop down selections in page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Assumptions:
There are two drop down menus on a single page, all MySQL driven, each one has it's own query, data in each table looks like this:

```
TABLE NAME tbl_1
FIELDS: seat, seat_desc, model_year, div_num

TABLE NAME tbl_2
FIELDS: model_year, model_year_desc

TABLE NAME: tbl_3
FIELDS: div_num, div_num_desc
```

EXAMPLE DATA:
[schema](http://cjneumann.net/images/tbls.png)

### Screen shot showing data sample.

'Keys' in each table are model_year and div_num.

The two drop downs are **Model Year** and **Seat Type**.  Each model year has a different Seat Type description.  For example, in 1966 seat A01 was a Black Bucket seat, whereas in 1967 A01 was a Green Bucket seat, and in 1968 A01 changed back to Black Bucket seat.

What I want to do:
When the user selects 1966, only the Seat Types for 1966 are available from the Seat Type drop down, because selecting 1966 "filters" the selection in the Seat Type drop down.

I would like a concise explanation because there are other examples that I would like to use the same concept, but I figured that this is a good place to start.  There are other data elements that are driven by year and division number.  'Function' page is .php with HTML table definitions and is included in the 'index.php' page.

What is the best way to do this?  JQuery?  Javascript?  Other EASY methodology?  I saw this fiddle but I am not sure how to integrate this into the page since I am not using straight HTML.
[JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/fRuhn/)

Thanks,
C

UPDATE:
I think that I am almost there, but still not working.  This dropdown works:

```
 public function ShowCategory()
        {                
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_gm_year";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $category = '<option value="0">--</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $category .= '<option value="' . $row['model_year_desc'] . '">' . $row['model_year'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $category;
    }

    public function ShowType()
    {
```

This one does not

```
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_gm_seat WHERE model_year=$_POST[model_year]";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $type = '<option value="0">--</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $type .= '<option value="' . $row['seat_desc'] . '">' . $row['seat'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $type;
    }
}

$opt = new SelectList();
```

Here is the HTML page with the drops

```
 <body>
    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
    <form id="select_form">
        Choose a category:<br />
        <select id="category">
            <?php echo $opt->ShowCategory(); ?>
        </select>
    <br /><br />
    Choose a type:<br />
    <select id="type">
         <option value="0">--</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

If someone needs a copy of the db and pages, let me know and I can provide them.

Thanks again!